# Install SQL Server 2012 management tools on Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, windows-xp

Can I install the SQL Server 2012 client tools on Windows XP? I see there is an x86 directory on the disk, but nothing in there to setup the management tools, and the main setup.exe doesn't run on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP [is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.110%29.aspx). You need Vista SP2 or higher.